# Installation Prestashop 1.7.6.4 problem "Make sure PHP has read access to the prestashop.zip file."

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am currently trying to install prestashop 1.7.6.4 via FTP ZileZilla but once I have transfered all the files on the server I get this message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAsg.png)

I tried to unzip and reload the file but it still didnot work...
WOuld any one have any idea how to fix this issue ?

Many thanks in advance,

Quentin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to proper file access for the directory where you've put prestashop.
In FileZilla you can right click directories and go to the access rights. Then check that everyone has the read permission.